# AD logontime to date in POWER BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to convert AD lastlogon to date. Even when Advanced editor shows no errors, custom column with my formula still shows an error
[image]

Comment: You are using DAX syntax in Power Query, where the code should be written in M. Either create a computed column, or change the code to M and use [the correct if statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/m-spec-conditionals).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this `if (condition) then (outcome) else (outcome)`. `if` `then` `else` must be lowercase

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlSK1YlWMlKKjQUA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each if [Column1]=1 then (1) else (0))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

vs

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlSK1YlWMlKKjQUA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each IF([Column1]=1,1,0))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: Token expected - your suggestion does not work

Comment: Expression.Error: The name 'IF' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly.

Comment: @Yuri can you please write `if` `then` `else` in lowercase only